# Blocked CORS Policy Web API Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have been spending hours and hours about looking a way to enable my front end web app (Angular) to access my Asp.NET MVC (Controller) but it displays the following error:

> http://localhost:49603/api/datapaths 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:49603/api/datapaths' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
>
> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:49603/api/datapaths", ok: false, …}

**proxy.conf.json:**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

**Package.json:**

Start line has been changed

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

**empolyee.service:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Empolyee } from './empolyee.model';
    import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class EmpolyeeService {
      formData: Empolyee;
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

      postEmpdata(formData: Empolyee){
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:49603/api/datapaths",formData);
      }
    }
```

**empdata.component.ts:**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmpolyeeService } from 'src/app/shared/empolyee.service';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-empdata',
      templateUrl: './empdata.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./empdata.component.css']
    })
    export class EmpdataComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private service:EmpolyeeService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.resetForm();
      }
      resetForm(form? : NgForm){
        if(form != null)
          form.resetForm();
        this.service.formData={
         empid : null,
         name : '',
         empcode : '',
         mobile : '',
         role : ''
        }
      }
      onSubmit(form: NgForm){
        this.insertRecord(form);
      }
      insertRecord(form: NgForm){
        this.service.postEmpdata(form.value).subscribe(res=>{
            this.resetForm(form)
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure this `target": "http://localhost:3000"` is shouldnot be `target": "http://localhost:49603"`

Comment: The proxy isn't going to work because your request doesn't actually go via the dev server (it would work with *relative* requests, yours is absolute). Also it's to port 3000 when your server is at 49603.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) and change `target": "http://localhost:3000"` to `target": "http://localhost:49603"` and try again

Comment: I have changed my target bro..after that also it is not working bro

Answer (score 1):

you need to add cors in backend side this is not a frontend issue

for example

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://systematixindia.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
   // Controller method`enter code here`s not shown...
}
```

Comment: I have added enable cors in webapiconfig file in app start

Comment: this is work for you?

Comment: no bro not working